# css border around two divs

Tags: html, css

Hello guys need your help by merging two `<div>`s' borders. Here is what I  want to get and what I've gotten until now:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46Y1f.jpg)
and this is what i want to do [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Lvgy.jpg)

Could someone please tell me how to do so? Here is my code if it helps something:

css :

```
#plink {

    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
}

#open {

    border-top: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;

}

#closed {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;

}

#closed:hover a {
    display: block;
}


#open:hover a {
    display: block;
}

#pbase {

    border: 1px solid black;
    position:relative;
    width: 600px;
    height: 300px;
    float: left;
}
```

and html :

```
<div id="plink">
<div id="open">My details</div>
<div id="closed"><a href="ads.php">My ads</a></div>
<div id="closed"><a href="fav.php">Favorites</a></div>
</div>
<div id="pbase"></div>
```

Comment: Could you be clearer in telling us what you want? Your explanation doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Try layering the `div`s in such a way that the tab ("My details") is on top and obscures part of the other `div` to make it look contiguous. You might have to set `border-right: 1px solid white` and `background-color: white` on the tab.

Comment: how can i do something like this http://i1292.photobucket.com/albums/...pshbytztun.jpg
i need to make an profile page with a 3 different layouts
for personal details , favorites , and ads .. or this http://i1292.photobucket.com/albums/b578/yahoo5000/civic/Untitled-1_zps2z5fdbcu.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#plink {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
}
#open {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid white;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
}
#closed {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
}
#pbase {
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: relative;
    width: 600px;
    height: 300px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: -1px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8rrov5hb/

This was achieved by setting #pbase with `margin-left: -1px` and `z-index: -1` to put it behind #plink

The div #open has `border-right: 1px solid white` to make it appear transparent - just change this to whatever background color you need

Comment: i got this http://i1292.photobucket.com/albums/b578/yahoo5000/civic/Untitled-1_zps4w8rcvqo.jpg

Comment: Are you sure #pbase has `border: 1px solid black`?

Comment: yes and i checked eveyrting its goes under my <div id="itemsCategLists"> div i mean if i set <div id="itemsCategLists"> background color to transperant then there will be a border of pbase this is cuz of z index

Comment: How can I know what #itemsCategLists is when it's not in the code you provided? Also, I'm not sure where you're getting the transparent background color?

Comment: If you look at the fiddle on the link I provided you will see how I achieved the styling effect

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Could you try to explain yourself better?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/egizz983/8jb1hs43/1/ i am trying to do what u did but i dont get the same result

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8jb1hs43/5/ try this. I removed the `z-index: -1` from #pbase and added `z-index: 10`to #plink

Comment: oh yea that working seems to be everything good and it his place as it shouldbe

Answer (score 0):

Set `border-right` color `white` and use `z-index` to keep open menu on over the right part. Try like following. Hope this will help you.

```
#open {
    border-color: black #fff black black;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    line-height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 199px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

**Update:**

```js
$('.menu a').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).closest('div').siblings().removeClass('open');
            $(this).closest('div').addClass('open');
        });
```

```css
#plink {
        position: relative;
        width: 200px;
        float: left;
    }

    .open {
        background-color: #a7a7ff !important;
        border-right: 1px solid #a7a7ff !important; 
        line-height: 50px;
        position: relative;
        text-align: center;
        z-index: 1;
    }

    .menu {
        border: 1px solid black;
        width: 200px;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 50px;
        background-color: #5e5eb6;
    }

    .menu:hover a {
        display: block;
    }


    .open:hover a {
        display: block;
    }

    #pbase {
        border: 1px solid black;
        position: relative;
        width: 600px;
        height: 300px;
        float: left;
        background-color: #a7a7ff;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="plink">
    <div class="menu open"><a href="details.php">My details</a></div>
    <div class="menu"><a href="ads.php">My ads</a></div>
    <div class="menu"><a href="fav.php">Favorites</a></div>
</div>
<div id="pbase"></div>
```

Comment: nope thats doest help cuz the div beside still have border and it shows anyway do not know why i though it will helps too but this just solve one other problem by double border above

Comment: i mean in total i want to make a profile system like ( My details , favorite , my ads ) do not know much ways so i am create 3 pages details.php ,fav.php , ads.php  with a diferents styles like i am trying to do now to get a right style . or if there are other way to do so please tel me

Comment: oh yea this looks nice and much better then 3 pages , but the question how to fit in a php code for each of them i mean there is just one pbase div ware all content set so i need to identifie somehow what to show

Comment: You can use `ajax` call to load the content of `pbase div` or if you want to load new page for each menu then use same `css` for each page.

Comment: yes i mean i have to set some class there or something cuz if ajax will load all content of pbase will be messy cuz there will be a code for a tree pages

Answer (score 0):

A couple of issues. You were using multiple id's with the same name, these should have been changed to classes. and 'open' / 'active' should be a state set with a class.

There was duplication in the css for the different states.

The main takeaway is that you needed to change the width of the active `.tab-nav'.

css was missing `box-sizing`

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.tab-navigation {

    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
}

.tab-nav {
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    background-color: white;
    width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
}

.tab-nav:last-of-type {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;  
}


.tab-nav:hover, .tab-nav.open {
    width: 202px;
}

.tab-nav a {
    display: block;
}


#pbase {

    border: 1px solid black;
    position:relative;
    width: 600px;
    height: 300px;
    float: left;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab-navigation">
  <div class="tab-nav open"><a href="details.php">My Details</a></div>
  <div class="tab-nav"><a href="ads.php">My ads</a></div>
  <div class="tab-nav"><a href="fav.php">Favorites</a></div>
</div>
<div id="pbase"></div>
```

Comment: okay i did your way but i got this http://i1292.photobucket.com/albums/b578/yahoo5000/civic/Untitled-1_zps4w8rcvqo.jpg

Comment: You must have missed something in the code. click 'run code snippet' above and make the screen full page. Don't know why this was downvoted. it meets the op's requirements.

Answer (score -2):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#plink').click(function(){
        $('#open, #pbase').css('border','2px solid #000');

    })

})

</script>
```

Comment: the border between open and pbase still did gone on click

Comment: Sorry, i can't get your comment bro.

Comment: just add after css .fadeout(1000);

Comment: your codes gives a border around #open and pbase but it will gives like border for them separately and i want to give them border as one div